# Migrate WebSite project into Asp.Net Core project

Tags: c#, web, asp.net-core-3.1, vs-web-site-project

How to migrate **Asp.Net WebSite** project into **Asp.Net Core 3.1**? I don't have knowledge on website application. There is no **.csproj** file while creating empty Website application in VS 2019. They have only Bin folder, web.config and package.config files.In web.config has mentioned only framework version not included the GUID and type of project(MVC or WebApi)

Comment: maybe this can help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: But as you mentioned the link, there is not described the website application